# ffmpeg receive "all" frames from stream before stopped by user

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to a preview of my webcam visible at all times, while allowing another process to record from it at will.

To this end I make `ffmpeg` preview my webcam with `sdl`, while streaming it.

```
 ffmpeg.exe `
-f dshow `
-i "video=webcam_video:audio=webcam_audio" `
-pix_fmt yuv420p `
-f sdl :0 `
-preset ultrafast `
-vcodec libx264 `
-x264-params keyint=1 `
-r 30 `
-f mpegts 'udp://239.0.0.1:1234'
```

When I'd like to record from it I run `ffmpeg` as a client like this

```
ffmpeg -y -re -i udp://239.0.0.1:1234 output.mp4;
```

When the command is executed `output.mp4` contains what's being recorded immediately, which is ideal.

However, when `q` is pressed the video is cut short (`output.mp4` is missing the last ~3 seconds of recording).

Is there a way to make `ffmpeg` "wait" until all frames recorded (on the server side) were received before the stop signal was given are collected, before closing?